4 excel display on 4 different monitor
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long

Private Const SWP_SHOWWINDOW As Long = &H40
Private Const HWND_TOPMOST As Long = -1

Function GetExcelWindowHandle(ByVal xlPID As Long) As Long
    Dim hwnd As Long
    Dim dwProcessID As Long
    Dim sClassName As String * 256
    
    hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, vbNullString) ' Get desktop window handle
    Do While hwnd <> 0
        Call GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, dwProcessID)
        If dwProcessID = xlPID Then
            Call GetClassName(hwnd, sClassName, 256)
            If Left$(sClassName, 6) = "XLMAIN" Then
                GetExcelWindowHandle = hwnd
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
        hwnd = GetWindow(hwnd, GW_HWNDNEXT)
    Loop
End Function
Sub PositionExcelInstances()
    Dim xlApp1 As Object, xlApp2 As Object
    Dim hwnd1 As Long, hwnd2 As Long
    Dim monitor1Left As Long, monitor1Top As Long, monitor2Left As Long, monitor2Top As Long
    Dim monitor1Width As Long, monitor1Height As Long, monitor2Width As Long, monitor2Height As Long
    
    ' Open Excel instances
    Set xlApp1 = CreateObject("C:\Users\juwaidah\Desktop\EMAD 398S\CAMERA INSP ON CASE - EMAD 398S.xlsx")
    Set xlApp2 = CreateObject("C:\Users\juwaidah\Desktop\EMAD 398S\ENSURE COMPONENTS FULLY SEATED AFTER DIP - EMAD 398S.xlsx")
    
    ' Adjust positions based on monitor resolutions (example resolutions)
    monitor1Left = 0
    monitor1Top = 0
    monitor1Width = 1366
    monitor1Height = 768
    
    monitor2Left = 1366 ' Assuming first monitor is on the left
    monitor2Top = 0
    monitor2Width = 1280
    monitor2Height = 1024
    
        ' Get handles of Excel instances
    hwnd1 = FindWindow("XLMAIN", xlApp1.Caption)
    hwnd1 = FindWindow("XLMAIN", xlApp1.Caption)
    
    ' Position Excel instance 1
    SetWindowPos hwnd1, HWND_TOPMOST, monitor1Left, monitor1Top, monitor1Width, monitor1Height, SWP_SHOWWINDOW
    
    ' Position Excel instance 2
    SetWindowPos hwnd2, HWND_TOPMOST, monitor2Left, monitor2Top, monitor2Width, monitor2Height, SWP_SHOWWINDOW
End Sub

hwnd1 = FindWindow("XLMAIN", xlApp1.Caption) and
hwnd1 = FindWindow("XLMAIN", xlApp1.Caption) was error
i cannot solved the problem.
if you have better idea please share.
i want to make a masterlist that just click on 1 button, then all designate excel show at every monitor. exp: 5 excel display at 5 monitor
please help..
thank you.
rgds.

Where from did you take the code you show? There are some obvious mistakes and typos... You do not create a new Excel session using Set xlApp1 = CreateObject("C:\Users\juw..."). If the respective workbook is already open you can Get these Excel session object using Set xlApp1 = GetObject("C:\Users\juw,,,").Application. Its window handle can be obtained using Debug.Print Hex(xlApp1.hwnd). Then, do you use Excel 32 bit? Otherwise, the API functions declarations must be adjusted for 64 bit and hwnd should be declared as LongPtr. Do you understand what you try doing, no offence?

What's happening when you try running your code? Should we understand that it does not raise any error? If errors, you should start with them, mentioning on which code lines they are raised and what description do they have...

You repeat the line hwnd1 = FindWindow("XLMAIN", xlApp1.Caption) twice and never set hwnd2

i just take from internet
